# Package mgcv insist in printing this error with my data

Tags: gam, mgcv

I have a data set, and my dependent variable has a lot of zeros (probably censored), so I tried to run a Tobit regression. However, I couldn't get my residuals to be evenly spread around zero (there seemed to be many more positive than negative residuals). Thus, I figured that maybe the relationships I'm looking for are not linear. Thus, I downloaded package `cenGAM`, which applies `mgcv`'s `gam` function, but to a Tobit regression. The problem is that I keep on getting this error, even though I got rid of all `NA`s in my set.

```
modGAM<-gam(Tempo_abdomen~
s(Tamanho)+
s(condicao)+
s(Tempo_movimento_aranha)+
Tratamento_cor,
data=dadosGAM,
family=tobit1(left.threshold=0))

Error in if (any(w < 0)) w <- 0.5 * as.numeric(Ddo$EDmu2 * mu.eta2) : 
  absent value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

All variables are continuous, except for `Tratamento_cor`, which is a 3 level factor, indicating three different colors (blue, red or gray).

Can someone tell me what this error means, and how to fix it?